# How do we move object from one array to another array on selecting that object using an API and ANGULAR 7?

Tags: arrays, angular, api, angular7

I have a list of employees array with `{"id", "name", "designation"}`, and now I have added a button to add some of them to managers array on clicking that button, all these arrays I have used via API. so how do we move one of the employees to managers array by clicking? I have tried something ... which was horribly wrong. so help me

HTML :

```
<div class="object center">
     <h5>{{emp.name}}</h5>
     <p>emp-id:{{emp.empid}}</p>
     <button class="btn" (click)="onPush(emp.empid)">Make manager</button> 
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
onPush(empid){
    this.httpClient.put('http://localhost:3000/manager/' + empid)
    .subscribe(success => {this.ngOnInit()}, error => {console.log("error")})
  }

}

// this is my API

{
  "employees": [
    {
      "empid": 214564567,
      "name": "kolerag",
      "designation":"lorem ipsum"
    },
    {
      "empid": 214345546,
      "name": "gunretro",
      "designation":"lorem ipsum"
     },
     {
      "empid": 2142225555,
      "name": "trevanew",
      "designation":"lorem ipsum"
     },

  ],
  "managers": []
  }
```

> So By clicking the button, the object from employees should append the
>   object to managers Array.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqvBZ.jpg)

Comment: Depends on what you are doing in the API. That's not explained in the question.

Comment: whats the question here?

Comment: I just wanted to move one of the employees to managers array, but I don't know how

Comment: @nikhilbodduluri You want to do it in client side or server?

Comment: client side @Arcteezy

Comment: @nikhilbodduluri Can you show the variables holding employee and manger data i.e. the structure of employee and manager

Comment: onPush(id){
    let data ={
      'id':this.id,
      'name':this.name,
      'designation':this.designation,
    }
    this.httpClient.put('http://localhost:3000/managers' + this.id + '/', data)
    .subscribe( success => {this.ngOnInit()} , error=>{console.log(error)})
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client side manipulation :

Assume `data` is the variable holding both employee and manager details.

```
data : {
    employess : {
        empid : number,
        name  : string,
        designation    : string
    }[],
    managers  : {
        empid : number,
        name  : string,
        designation    : string
    }[]
}

onPush(id){

    // Temporary variable
    let temp : {
        empid : number,
        name  : string,
        designation    : string
    } = this.data.employees.find(emp=>emp.empid==id);

    // Add to managers array
    this.data.managers.push(temp);

    // Slice from employees
    this.data.employees = this.data.employees.filter(emp=>emp.empid!=id);

}
```